# How to change the distance between a pin label and the pin line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes

The distance between the pin line and the plot can be changed by `inner sep`. How to change the distance between the pin label and the pin line?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[domain=1:6]
        {exp(x)};
        54.59815
        \node[coordinate,pin={[pin edge={blue,ultra thick}]left:{A pin!} } ]
            at (axis cs:4,54.59815) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image]

How to get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to add the `inner sep=0pt` option after the `left` one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[domain=1:6]
        {exp(x)};
        54.59815
        \node[coordinate,pin={[pin edge={blue,ultra thick}]left,inner sep=0pt:{A pin!}} ]
            at (axis cs:4,54.59815) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For defining this property globally you can define your own pin style that takes the text label as argument in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{mypin/.style={coordinate,pin={[pin edge={blue,ultra thick}]left,inner sep=0pt:{#1}}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[domain=1:6]
        {exp(x)};
        \node[mypin={A pin!}] at (axis cs:4,54.59815) {};
        \node[mypin={Another pin!}] at (axis cs:5,148,41) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the exact answer. Is there any way to set this to apply to all the `pin`s?

Comment: @M.Reza see my edits

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I have many `tikzpicture`s with `pin` and the reason I wan to configure this setting globally is to avoid individual changes to the `tikzpicture`s. Is there any way to incorporate this change into the original `pin`, not defining a new one?